# How to get contact list of a facebook user in grails using spring-security-rest:1.4.0.RC5

Tags: facebook, rest, grails, spring-security, facebook-oauth

I am using spring-security-rest:1.4.0.RC5 api to login with facebook, twitter, linkedin and googleplus in my grails application. I am able to fetch user details like first name, email etc. But I am not getting the contact list of user. How can I get the contact list of the user.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can take help from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends

Comment: Thank you Abdullah.
I am giving the permission of user_friends in my application and on facebook. But then also I am not getting friend list.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 2 of the graph API you can no longer get the complete list of a user's friends. Instead, you only see the friends who have also authorized your application. This is by design as Facebook does not want developers to be taking list of friends and taking their info.

If you registered for your application key before v2 was released then you can continue to use the old API which allows for this functionality. However, [all apps will be automatically upgraded](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading) on April 30th, 2015 so you won't be able to use it for long.